# How measure used memory of java application?

Tags: java, memory, space

I run JConsole. There are Eden space, Heap memory usage, etc.
I think that minimum memory used is Eden space + Survivor + Code cache.
Because other memory used only temporary.
Does it correct? Thanks.

Comment: not sure i understand the question. you can use jstat to watch the jvm and GCs or take a heap dump to see whats taking up space. what exactly do you need?

Comment: I need estimate how memory need for application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the minimum memory used, trigger a GC and see the total memory used at that point.  For the application to run efficiently it may need to more, but this is the minimum.